# Apache serving modified static assets incorrectly: serves obsolete file with sizes adjusted to match that of the new file

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, mod-deflate, cakephp

I've got a CakePHP project running in a CentOS VirtualBox. The website is served with Apache 2.2.15.

There are JS files in the document root folder. Apache seemed to serve them file.

But after i edit a JS file, Apache would serve the old file. It will modify the size of the old file to match the size of the new file and serve the modified old file:

- If the new file is smaller than the old file, it would cut the old file and serve the result;
- If the new file is larger than the old file, it would append `�` symbols to the old file and serve the result.

Restarting Apache does not resolve the issue.

The only way i found to make Apache serve the current file is to move the file to another location. Then CakePHP will display a fancy 404 page. Then i move the file back, and Apache displays the file in it's current state.

But i2.2.15t will freeze the file in that state and after modifying the file again i will have to repeat the trick again.

Apache logs are clean, the access log file displays this:

> 172.28.128.1 - - [12/Jul/2014:07:42:13 -0400] "GET /assets/js/compiled/editable_group.js HTTP/1.1" 200 903

What is the reason of the problem and how do i resolve it?

PS I will be happy to provide any details, logs, configs, etc. Just tell me what you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found the answer in this question:

[Apache on CentOS 5.9 VM serves modified files incorrectly](https://serverfault.com/questions/548492/apache-on-centos-5-9-vm-serves-modified-files-incorrectly?rq=1)

The solution is to include `EnableSendfile off` into the `<directory>` section in the Apache config.

Comment: Please accept your own answer as correct, so everyone sees the question is answered properly.

Comment: I tried, but StackOverflow won't let me do it: *You can accept your own answer in 2 days*.